# How to update a postgres table and migrate data from another table with better performance on large data - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, database-performance, data-migration

I have following two tables in my potgres database with each type.

user

```
userid       | bigint (PK) NOT NULL
username     | character varying(255)
businessname | character varying(255)
```

inbox

```
messageid    | bigint (PK) NOT NULL
username     | character varying(255)
businessname | character varying(255)
```

Upto now the referencing to `user` table from `inbox` happens using `username` and `businessname` fields without foreign key constraints. My intention is to introduce a new field to `inbox` as `userRefId` and refer to the `userid` in `user` table without a foreign key so i can drop `username` and `businessname` fields which has been a bad way of lookup up for `user` from `inbox`.

For now i've prepared postgres `ALTER` and `UPDATE` queries to do this migration, but the issue is its taking so much time in live database with too much records. So now i want to create a stored procedure to do this task.

Queries

```
ALTER TABLE inbox ADD userRefId bigint;

UPDATE inbox SET userRefId = (SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username=inbox.username AND 
businessname=inbox.businessname) WHERE (SELECT userid FROM user WHERE username=inbox.username AND
businessname=inbox.businessname) IS NOT NULL;
```

What is the best approach to address this issue? Improving this existing query with indexing or crating a stored procedure. Provided examples are highly appreciated as i'm fairly new.

Comment: As a side note: using a "magic" number like 255 for the max length of a `varchar` column has no performance or storage advantages over e.g. 342 or 271.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically an UPDATE with a FROM clause is faster than a co-related subquery

```
UPDATE inbox 
  SET userRefId = u.userid
from "user" u
WHERE u.username = inbox.username 
  AND u.businessname = inbox.businessname
```

Comment: Any suggestion for a stored procedure option?

Comment: @dineshalwis: the UPDATE won't be faster if you put it into a stored procedure.